# IMPORTXML- Could not fetch URL

Tags: html, web-scraping, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to scrape data from wine-searcher.com and am having an issue with IMPORTXML in google sheets, I keep getting the "could not fetch url" error when trying either of the following:

=IMPORTXML("https://www.wine-searcher.com/find/robert+mondavi+rsrv+cab+sauv+napa+valley+county+north+coast+california+usa","//h1")

=IMPORTXML("https://www.wine-searcher.com/find/robert+mondavi+rsrv+cab+sauv+napa+valley+county+north+coast+california+usa","//*[@id='tab-info']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/span[2]/span[2]") ( xpath to scrape current average price)

I've tried suggestions in other stack posts such as with/out http/s, www, and both XPath and full XPath to no avail. I have also tried with other URLs and they work no problem, maybe the problem is with URL length or format? Any help would be appreciated. If it cannot be done with IMPORT XML, any free alternatives suggested?

Comment: This specific website is controlled by JavaScript so you cannot scrape values from it.

Answer (score 1):

As the page is built in javascript on the client side and not on the server side, you will not be able to retrieve the data by the importxml / importhtml functions. However, the page contains a json which you can retrieve and analyze to retrieve the information you need.

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = 'https://www.wine-searcher.com/find/robert+mondavi+rsrv+cab+sauv+napa+valley+county+north+coast+california+usa'
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.split('<script type="application/ld+json">')[1].split('</script>')[0]
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  Logger.log(data)
}
```

all these informations are available, from x=0 to x=23

```
data.offers[x].@type
data.offers[x].priceCurrency
data.offers[x].availability
data.offers[x].priceValidUntil
data.offers[x].url
data.offers[x].name
data.offers[x].seller.@type
data.offers[x].seller.name
data.offers[x].seller.description
data.offers[x].seller.availableDeliveryMethod
data.offers[x].seller.address.@type
data.offers[x].seller.address.addressRegion
data.offers[x].seller.address.addressCountry.@type
data.offers[x].seller.address.addressCountry.name
data.offers[x].priceSpecification.@type
data.offers[x].priceSpecification.description
data.offers[x].priceSpecification.price
data.offers[x].priceSpecification.priceCurrency
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17f6lhaHA_xpSWClzxkYZcNs4FeM4VHA480QrmwyJvT4/copy

Answer (score -1):

as mentioned both these basic formulae return nothing:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.wine-searcher.com/find/robert+mondavi+rsrv+cab+sauv+napa+valley+county+north+coast+california+usa"; "//*")
```

---

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://www.wine-searcher.com/find/robert+mondavi+rsrv+cab+sauv+napa+valley+county+north+coast+california+usa")
```

pls note that importing data into spreadsheet is URL specific, so if something works well for ***[www.aaa.org](http://www.aaa.org)*** most likely it wont work for ***[www.bbb.org](http://www.bbb.org)***